# How export data from excel to create a timeline in R using timevis

Tags: r, excel, timeline

So, I'm in a research project about the social isolation caused by the COVID-19 and the and its impacts on domestic violence. I need to create a timeline of some important events but i don't know how import the data from excel and make the timeline using timevis package. This is what i have in the moment:

```
    data <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  content = c("1", "2", "3", 
              "4", "5"),
  start = c("2021-03-13", "2021-03-16", "2021-03-19", 
            "2021-03-21", "2021-03-23"),
  end = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)

timevis(data)

editable = TRUE
```

The problem is: there is more than 3k events that I need to put in the time line and its all in a excel file, the first column have the name of the event and the second one has the date. I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried reading the excel file into R?, there are several packages you can use for example `openxlsx`. `readxl`, `xlsx` and others, a quick search will help.

Comment: I tried using readxl and worked, thanks a lot